# Failed to write request in a MockMvc test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use spring boot 3.2, I do a basic test

```
@Test
void getListAvisByDepotId() throws Exception{

        BillRecord alr = new BillRecord(23L, "2", LocalDate.now());

        Mockito.when(bill.getBill(Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.any(PageRequest.class))).thenReturn(new PageImpl(Arrays.asList(alr)));



        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
                "/bill/268/ads").accept(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

}
```

Actually  only error i get is

> Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
> Body = {"type":"about:blank","title":"Internal Server Error","status":500,"detail":"Failed to write request","instance":"/bill/268/ads"}

Edit, add controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/bill")
public class BillController { {

    @Autowired
    BillService billService;

    @GetMapping("/{billId}/ads")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<BillRecord>> getBill(@PathVariable Long billId,
                                                                     @ParameterObject @PageableDefault(direction = Sort.Direction.ASC, sort = "billDate", size=Integer.MAX_VALUE) Pageable pageable) {

        Pageable newPageRequest = BindingPageRequestHelper.binding(BindingPageRequestHelper.billPageSort(), pageable);

        Page<BillRecord> pageBills = billService.getBill(billId, newPageRequest);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(pageBills, HttpStatus.OK);
    });
}
```

Controller is called correctly, parameter value is ok

Comment: Can you also show as a update of the question your controller method that you are trying to test ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to:

```
@GetMapping("/{billId}/ads")
public ResponseEntity<Page<BillRecord>> getBill(@PathVariable("billId") Long billId,
                                                @ParameterObject @PageableDefault(direction = Sort.Direction.ASC, sort = "billDate", size=Integer.MAX_VALUE) Pageable pageable) {

}
```

It's likely due to a mismatch between the path variable defined in your controller method and the path variable used in your URL pattern.

You can also try to change the test:

```
 MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/bill/{billId}/ads", 268L)
```

If you can reach your controller in debug mode you can check the parameter and confirm that you get the right one.

I see that you updated your question if you changed your controller argument to `billId` you need to do the same in your service `billService.getBill(depotId, newPageRequest);`
Since you can debug, it should be relatively easy to figure out at what stage you have a problem.

Comment: just update, don't change nothing

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add value to the @PathVariable, I've updated my answer, try again.

Comment: controller was already called...that change nothing

Comment: yes i can reach controller via break point... this change do nothing